# AWS and Niginx server relationship

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

### I want to know how there exists this relationship

- There is a AWS-server
- Each AWS-Server has instances namely `1,2,3.....n`
- Each instances i can have many ports like `7001,7002.....etc`

**so,**

- Now if i use `NodeJS server` which is basically a `Niginx server`  other
  wise `Apache`

---

***does this mean that a server is running on a server***

---

Confused - Im confused !

***Can someone clear this !***

Comment: The word "Server" can be used to describe a physical (or virtual) machine, the server operating system, and even the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically:

1. AWS Server - this means a physical server, or a virtual machine running inside a physical server in a datacenter.
2. Ubuntu Server - it's an example of operating systems designed to run on servers (the meaning on point 1)
3. NodeJS, Nginx, Apache - pieces of software that fulfill a "Server" role in a "client-server" architecture. Generally, this software runs on "servers" (the meaning on point 1) but they can also run on any other computer system.